# vb.net WCF Service "process" type

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I need to get a list of all of the running processes on a machine.  Since the GUI runs as AsInvoker, it has a hard time reliably getting the full paths of all of the processes.  So I created a service, and I was going to pass the process to a function in the service.

```
        For Each currentProcess As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
            processPath = MyService.GetProcessPath(currentProcess).ToLower()
        Next
```

Everything is set up correctly because I can pass strings back and forth if I use string types.  But when I use a "process" type, it quits working and gives the following error.  How do I add the "process" type?

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException occurred
  Message=There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:p. The InnerException message was 'Type 'System.Diagnostics.Process' with data contract name 'Process:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Diagnostics' is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.

Comment: Did you try doing what the suggestions said?

Comment: I am not sure what it is trying to tell me to do, so I have been googling it for 10 hours today.  I researched KnownTypeAttribute attribute and also researched "adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer".  But I am kind of a newbie with .net and I just do not understand what it is telling me to do ;).

Comment: Here is the fix in case anyone is interested.

<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()> _
Public Class ServerProcess

    <DataMember()> _
    Public processPath As String = ""

    <DataMember()> _
    Public ProcessId As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal processId As Integer, ByVal processPath As String)
        Me.ProcessId = processId
        Me.processPath = processPath

    End Sub